# How do I find a query that was used to create a new table?

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a table in `Access` that shows an output to a query.

How can I find the query that was written to create the table, as I need this to create the same table for a data update? I don't have access to the tables that were queried to create the output table, but I have access to the new tables that I need to import the query into to create the output table.

I have tried :

```
SELECT DISTINCT MSysObjects.Name
FROM MSysQueries INNER JOIN MSysObjects ON MSysQueries.ObjectId=MSysObjects.Id
WHERE (((MSysQueries.Name1) Like "*" & [TableName] & "*")) OR (((MSysQueries.Name2) Like "*" & [TableName] & "*"))
```

But it doesn't tell me what the query is that was able to create that table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way in Access, but you can [import the Access database into SQL Server](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/ms-access-to-sql-database/) (free versions can easily be obtained). The general gist of this is to right click an existing database and choose `Import data`, then choose MS Access as the data source. The link also explains how to import it as a new database. There's plenty of examples available if you google importing access to SQL.

Once you've imported the database to SQL, right Click on your database inside SQL Server Management Studio, select `Script database as` then `Create to new query editor`. You can also do this for individual tables:

[image: Right click option in SQL]

Hope this helps, even if it's a bit long winded!